# Generating value in Entity Framework Core with FirstOrDefaultAsync()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework, is it better to create a generated ID from a previous record and set default value to **1** if none exists or use a SQL Server constraint in FirstOrDefaultAsync()?

**Code example:**

```
public int GenerateHistId(string sessionId)
{
   int lastId = 1;
   var lastEntry = context.LETItems_Histories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Sessionid == sessionId);

   if (lastEntry.Result.Histid.Equals(null)) 
      {
         return lastId = 1; 
      }
      else
      {
         lastId++;
      }
   
   return lastId;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence? If so, set Identity on the PK field if you're using MS SQL

Comment: Nope not a sequence, Ill be doing a search on histId to retrieve a list of all items with a particular ID at some point.

Comment: You should let your database generate your ids for you. Why do you need an id if the entity does not exist? Can you return nullable int here with no value?

Comment: It's not an identity field. I will eventually do a search on the result set to find all records with a specific HistId.

Comment: Trying to do this client-side creates what is called a "Race Condition." Two or more concurrent client processes could attempt to do this, see the same maximum number in the database (e.g.: 47), and then try to create new records with the same number (e.g.: 48). You say you don't want an identity field, but it sounds very much like you need either an identity field or a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) to ensure unique numbers.